# p5.js Changing size using variables

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to know how to change the size/location of an object in p5 using an infinite loop.
for some reason, this doesn't work

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}
var size=80

function draw() {
  noFill();
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    rectMode(CENTER);
  background(220);
  ellipse(40,40,size);
rect(40, 40, size, size);
  
}
test()
function test()
{
  size=size+1
  draw()
  setTimeout(test, 200)
}
```

How do i do it?

Also, here's the error message:

> p5.js says: There's an error due to "noFill" not being defined in the
> current scope (on line 77 in about:srcdoc [about:srcdoc:77:3]).
>
> If you have defined it in your code, you should check its scope,
> spelling, and letter-casing (JavaScript is case-sensitive). For more:
> https://p5js.org/examples/data-variable-scope.html
> https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_Defined#What_went_wrong
> Did you just try to use p5.js's noFill() function? If so, you may want
> to move it into your sketch's setup() function.
>
> For more details, see:
> https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup

Comment: Try changing `setTimeout(test(), 200)` to `setTimeout(test, 200)` -- setTimeout expects a function. `test` is a function, while `test()` calls a function, and returns a value (in this case `undefined`)

Comment: That may have helped, but that's not the problem...

Comment: why are you calling the function draw yourself? p5 automatically calls draw from within itself and gives it the proper scope. It seems like you are wanting to call `setInterval(()=>size++, 200);` in the `setup` function (and also declare `size` above the function call of setup)

Comment: can... you put that in the answers section? also, I'm getting the whole page of code and that just happen to be in the template I either delete or let exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the error is because the you're calling `draw()` before `noFill`, `ellipse`, `rectMode`... etc are defined, which seems to happen after your javascript. You can verify this by replacing `test()` with `setTimeout(test)`, which shouldn't have that error because it should run the code after the p5 functions are defined.

In any case, as Samathingamajig says, you generally shouldn't call `draw` by yourself-- p5 automatically does it, defaulting to aiming to call it 60 times a second. You can just fix your code by deleting the `draw()` line.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}
var size=80

function draw() {
  noFill();
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  background(220);
  ellipse(40,40,size);
  rect(40, 40, size, size);
}
test()
function test()
{
  size=size+1
  setTimeout(test, 200)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally functions like rectMode and ellipseMode are called in the setup function. Here is what your code should look like:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}
var size = 80

function draw() {
  background(220);
  rect(40, 40, size, size);
  ellipse(40, 40, size);
  noFill();
}
```